# Why can't I put <script> tags in my @section?

Tags: laravel

I have a `@section('content')` in a file `home.blade.php` which extends `@extends('layouts.app')`, for simplicity I'll use the generated Laravel scaffolding as an example.

`home.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    You are logged in!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I try and add a script tag to the section:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    You are logged in!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/example.js"></script> <!-- Adding my script here -->
@endsection
```

But then I get the following error in the console:

```
app.js:38355 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.
```

It says avoid placing script tags in templates? What exactly does this mean? How can I place a script within a `@section`, I don't want to put the script in my `@extends('layouts.app')`, I only want my script to work for this `@section` area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Blade stacks, they allow you to specifiy JavaScript for child views. In your `home.blade.php` add the following:

```
@push('scripts')
<script src="js/example.js"></script>
@endpush
```

This will push your script to a stack named `scripts`, you can name your stack to whatever you want. Then in your `app.blade.php` call the stack within your `<head>` tag as follows:

```
 @stack('scripts')
```

Now your `example.js` file will only load for `home.blade.php`. Any other views that extend `app.blade.php` will not load this file.